Would it be possible to apply Seifert Van Kampen to get fundamental group of a circle?
In the notes that I studied from, the fundamental group of $S^1$ by covering space theory. I am trying to figure if one can do it by Seifert Van Kampen too.
For this end, I must construct two open sets in the circle which union into the circle. Of course, these choosen sets must have some overlap as the circle is a connected space. After attempting for some time, I am coming to the conclusion that it should be mathematically impossible to calculate the circle's fundamental group by Van Kampen directly because when you choose two such open sets then they must neccesarily have some form of path disconnected overlap.



Is this really true? If so how would one prove this?

Note: I have put an attempt to this question by myself as an answer.

In order to compute anything other than the trivial group with Seifert-Van Kampen, you need at least one space with non-trivial $\pi_1$ (and specifically, at least one open subset of your space with non-trivial $\pi_1$).

There's a version of van Kampen for fundamental groupoids that lets you compute the fundamental group of the circle.  See section 6.7 in Brown's Topology and Groupoids book.

Here is what I think could be an answer to this. Suppose there were to open subset (neither equal to circle itself) of the circle $U,V $ whose intersection was not path disconnected. Then since path connectedopen set in general on the circle are curved interval, their fundamental group is trivial. We have then the equality that
$$\mathbb{Z} = \{ e \} *_{\sim}\{ e \}$$
Well of course, if we take the free product of the trivial group quotiented by any relation is again trivial. This would give $\mathbb{Z} =e$. Contradiction. Meaning, if there was a non disjoint partition of the circle into two open set they would have an intersection always.
Hope this is correct. Would be interestted in ways to show this also without Seifert Van Kampen.
